# Superscript on density matrix

Tags: homework-and-exercises, soft-question, terminology, quantum-optics

I have been asked in homework to solve the optical bloch equation for the initial condition of $\rho_{22}=0,\rho_{12}=0$. Professor gave a hint of the general equation and let us carry it from here. The general equation is, $\rho_{ij}=\rho_{ij}^{(1)}+\rho_{ij}^{(2)}e^{i\Omega t}+\rho_{ij}^{(3)}e^{-i\Omega t}$.

I don't understand the superscript on density matrix. Could you tell me what it is?

Comment: Hi ! Do you have a specific physics concept to ask about ? In case you haven't already done so, please go through the site [guidelines](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: it looks to me like this is a specific concept - i.e. what is represented by the superscripts!

Comment: You should be more specific to what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your professor's trying to tell you that the general solution will be a sum of three terms, and he could have just as easily used $f_{ij}$, $g_{ij}$ and $h_{ij}$ for the three superscript terms.

Edit: In other words, you're Matrix $\rho$ can be expressed as a sum of matrices $\rho^{(1)}$, $\rho^{(2)}$, which is proportional to $e^{i\Omega t}$ and as such has a phase that rotates with frequency $\Omega$, and a counter-rotating term $\rho^{(3)}$ proportional to $e^{-i\Omega t}$

There's no formal meaning tied to $^{(k)}$ that I know of. (Edit: Sebastian Riese is, of course, correct)

Comment: Well, $f^{(k)}$ is quite common for the $k$-th derivative of $f$ or for the $k$-th order term in a perturbation series, but both are certainly not meant here.

Comment: @GeckoGeorge I know what he want to ask. He is talking about the general solution of the Optical Bloch equation. Visit this [link](http://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjABahUKEwidnKWblJbGAhXFLKYKHaw7AE4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kip.uni-heidelberg.de%2Fmatterwaveoptics%2Fteaching%2Farchive%2Fws04-05%2FAtomLight.pdf&ei=VhuBVZ2ZMcXZmAWs94DwBA&usg=AFQjCNGxLuVWPmGI4GbKRfTCzVkv4BGD7g&sig2=KF9I25gMKwvRdimdwex-CQ) Page 4. I think his professor want him to solve the general solution of special initial condition, and he don't understand superscript on general solution.

Comment: In that case, I feel I've answered the question. Since no further questions are asked, I'm not sure how to clarify the answer any more, though I'll give it a quick try.